# Special characters break when saving a file

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, octave, figure

While running the following program, Octave displays a figure with a legend saying `ä`. However the figure in the saved pdf file displays `^/`. It's the same for other formats like png or jpeg. Any ideas how to fix this? I did search for quite some while but I somehow didn't manage to find a solution.

I'm using version 4.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
x = linspace(1,10)
y= sin(x)
plot(x,y)
legend('ä')
print('test.pdf')
```

---

Edit:
So I did find a possible solution to this problem:

```
print('test.pdf','dpdfcairo')
```

This produces the following error:

> error: print.m: PDFCAIRO output is not available for GL2PS output

Searching for the error message leads me to old gnuplot threads and I am a bit lost as to how to fix this.

Comment: Could it be the file encoding?

Comment: thanks, your suggestion at least got me closer to fixing this.

Comment: When you do solve the problem, please post it on here as an answer and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the line

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
```

at the beginning and use `'-dpdfcairo'` instead of `'dpdfcairo'`.

I guess Octave is loading `qt` or `fltk` graphics toolkit by default, but using `pdfcairo` is just supported with `gnuplot`. From [Octave documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html):

> Generate Cairo based output when using the Gnuplot graphics toolkit.

So the complete code is:

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
x = linspace(1,10);
y= sin(x);
plot(x,y);
legend('ä');
print('test.pdf', '-dpdfcairo');
```